# Zend_XmlRpc_Client can't communicate with Zend_Xml_Security::scan

Tags: php, security, magento, xml-rpc

I have a process A that is communicating with a Magento app B using XML_RPC. I recently deployed Magento SUPEE6788 and process A couldn't communicate with Magento app B anymore.

I noticed that the patch SUPEE6788 changed the following file : app/code/core/Zend/XmlRpc/Request.php changing to :

```
Zend_Xml_Security::scan($request);
```

However, I'm calling my Magento app B in process A using the following line :

```
 $xmlrpc_client = new Zend_XmlRpc_Client('http://my.app.B/index.php/api/xmlrpc');
 $xmlrpc_client->getHttpClient()->setConfig(array('useragent' => 'my_super_user_agent','timeout' => 3600,'keepalive' => true, 'persistent' => true));
 try {   
     $session = $xmlrpc_client->call...
 }
```

What should I change in process A so that it can communicate with app B ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

The issue was in my client URL. I removed the "index.php" and it worked fine.